# subscript out of range in do while

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from one workbook to another for a variable amount of rows, dictated by the "ending" variable. The problem is, I get a subscript out of range error on the first line of the Do While loop. I have tried changing the Range to many different values, including static ones (like "A23") to no avail. What else can I try?

```
i = 1
    If Not i = ending Then
        Do
            Worksheets("wsS2").Range("A" & 23 + i).copy
            Worksheets("wsS1").Range ("A" & 15 + i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop While Not i = ending
    End If
```

Comment: You probably don't have a worksheet named "wsS2" in the active workbook when the loop runs. Also, the 2nd line of the loop's body does absolutely nothing. Or did you cut off an underscore after `.Copy`?

Comment: When do you get the error? In the first iteration of the loop or afterwards?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I apologize, wsS2 is defined earlier in the code as "Raw Data", and I do have a sheet with that name. as for the underscore... yes, I did cut that off. I will replace it and see i that works!

Comment: You can get rid of the `If Not i = ending Then` test by changing the loop to `Do Until i = ending ... Loop`.

Comment: @FDavidov I'm not sure. Is there a way to check that without actually testing it on the workbook?

Comment: If `wsS2` is a variable, remove the quotes.  Same for `wsS1`.

Comment: ^^ that is the problem.

Comment: Removing the quotes did it, thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If wsS2 is a variable, remove the quotes. Same for wsS1. – Comintern

Removing the quotes does it!